# WP7 TextBlock to visible on button press

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have 1 TextBox, 1 TextBlock and 1 Button.

When button is pressed, I want the TextBlock to be visible only is there is no data within the TextBox. If there is data within the TextBox, then I want it to continue to the next page (Page1).

When I run the code and click on the button; regardless of if there is data in the TextBox or not, the button will send me to the next Page1 where it is only supposed to go if there is text in the TextBox (I test this without any text in the TextBox).

```
 private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ProfileNameTextBox.Text == null)
        {
            textBlockError.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Try changing your check for text to `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`
2. What does the value show when you debug it?
3. Your logic doesn't match your statement "I want the TextBlock to be visible only is there is no data within the TextBox." From your code, you are hiding the textbox when there is no data...

Comment: I am sorry about the code 'textBlockError.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;' as i was testing the opposite way with still nothing working and forgot to change the code before i submitted it here. my mistake. and I will try your solution as soon as I can, thank you